# How can I read a slice with other size in crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I would like to read 1st 2bytes of a file as “unsigned int”.

I checked the thread
"[Crystal reading x bytes from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550526/crystal-reading-x-bytes-from-file)"
and I could get 1st 2bytes with following code.

```
File.open("./test/test_data") do |io|
  buffer = Slice(UInt8).new(2)
  bytes_read = io.read(buffer)
  buffer = buffer[0, bytes_read]
  pp buffer
end
```

However, this code returns "2 UInt8"

```
$ crystal test2.cr
buffer # => Slice[0, 6]
```

How can I read this "2 UInt8" as "1 UInt16"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.open("test/test_data") do |io|
  p UInt16.from_io(io, IO::ByteFormat::LittleEndian)
end
```

[Int.from_io](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.18.7/Int.html#from_io%28io%3AIO%2Cformat%3AIO%3A%3AByteFormat%29-class-method)

Comment: The same can be done with `IO#read_bytes` (maybe a bit more idiomatic): `io.read_bytes(UInt16, IO::ByteFormat::LittleEndian)`

Comment: Thank your for both quick answer. I could confirm that both code work well.